# how to make a drop down content flow to right when overflowing

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a drop down component (in Reactjs), and I am having trouble on how to make it not pop up outside the browser width.

I have tried to set `right: 0px`, it works fine when the dropdown is at the rightmost of the panel, but if the dropdown is not then it gets messed up.

[here](https://codepen.io/RayTang/pen/YMPBLP) is the codepen for the sample.

here is a sample css

```
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

here is a sample html

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

[image: here is a screenshot for the behavior], you can notice that there is a scrollbar there.

What I want to achieve is that I can right align the drop down content, relative to the drop down header.

Thanks

Comment: can you show portions of the relevant code on here and not just link it?

Comment: Are you open to a solution using JavaScript?

Comment: I am trying to achieve it by using either pure css or React+css, so JavaScript might not be that ideal

Comment: React+css will involve you writing some JavaScript right? What you're asking for is a pretty common problem when dealing with menus. You can use [react-popper](https://github.com/FezVrasta/react-popper) or derive inspiration from there on how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to adjust right side dropdown contents. One possible way is as follow

```
 <div class="dropdown-content d2">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
 </div>
```

`.d2 {
  right:0;
}`

Ping me if you have any query.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  float: right;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}
  
  
div.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.d2 {
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content d2">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>
  
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">some other dropdown</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP has already tried this. _"I have tried to set right: 0px, it works fine when the dropdown is at the rightmost of the panel, but if the dropdown is not then it gets messed up."_

Comment: you have to set different styles on the base of location e.g. now you have to menus one aligned to right and one to left. That is why I have added separate class for right side menu. 
You can share you full template if you have more queries in adjustments of menus.
You can also conditionally add classes to style dropdowns depending on position.

Comment: I'm just trying to get the OP's question answered. Just change the order of Home, News and Dropdown and you'll see the problem that OP is trying to explain.

Comment: the ultimate goal for this question is to make the dropdown content right align to the dropdown header's container, and I want a more generic solution that making different style for different control because I need to make the web site multilingual, and hardcoding every right align drop down is simply impossible.

Comment: do you have any mock of end result you wanna achieve like what column layout you wanna make. 2 or 3 col layout or top header with right align items and left side nav etc.

Because that way we can just hit and try and unable to give appropriate solution.

Comment: by looking at mocks we can identify css limitations and possibilities current example have no hierarchy.